# Center text in a mat-select's mat-option

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, mat-select

I'm trying to center the text inside a `<mat-option>` that's nested in a `<mat-select>`, as such:

```
<mat-select #listMenu>
    <mat-option>TEST1</mat-option>
    <mat-option>TEST2</mat-option>
    <mat-option>TEST3</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And this is the desired result:

[image]

I've been able to achieve it in a very hacky way, and there's nothing in the documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: Define the CSS styling rule in global stylesheet**

> styles.scss

```
.mat-mdc-option {
  justify-content: center !important;

  .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

**Approach 2: Turning off the ViewEncapsulation mode**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  ...,
  styles: `
    .mat-mdc-option {
      justify-content: center !important;

      .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
        margin-right: 0 !important;
      }
    }
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tx4e3n?file=src%2Fexample%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

Reference: [3 Correct Ways To Overwrite Angular Material Styles](https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962)

Comment: Worked! Comprehensive answer and an awesome reference. Thanks.